# PyCaffe got different gradients for each run of net.backward?

Tags: python, c++, caffe

Today, I got a really weird thing.

I load a caffe model, feed input, net.forward, check the output data, perfect.
Then, I feed labels to the bottom layer blobs.diff, net.backward, then check the gradients (params.diff) with the result from same model caffe c++ program. They were different.

Further, when I continued to run net.backward several times at python, each time I got different gradients. This is not the case for C++ programs, they keep the same no matter how many time you run net.backward, as long as you did not change the bottom diff.

I check the bottom layer's blobs and diff, they kept unchanged both in python and C++ programs, and weights were also unchanged. This was really weird.

Anyone can provide some hints? I can provide codes if it is necessary.

Here is part of the codes :

def train_one_step(X, y, lr) :

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = X

#Forward, to get the softmax output

output = net.forward()

prob = output['prob']

#Calculate the loss of cross entropy loss function

net.blobs['prob'].diff[:] = y[:] - prob[:]

#Calculate the gradients of net parameter

net.backward()

#Renew weights based on gradients and learning rate

for key in net.params:

    net.params[key][0].data[:] += lr * net.params[key][0].diff[:]

    net.params[key][1].data[:] += lr * net.params[key][1].diff[:]

return loss, prob
```

I just want to dig out my own step function (the step of solver), so  I can make some trick on the loss before it backwards, and something else. I know this is quite low efficient, data between GPU, CPU exchanged a lot.

In order to test it, I kept input the same sample(same X, y), you get different diff data. That means this function cannot work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: How different are the gradients?  Did you do anything to fix the random seed used to initialize the model in each language?  My first guess is that the C++ RNG (random-number generator) has a constant default seed, but the Python one uses system time.

Comment: Thanks, @Prune. I thought no one were interested in this problem. But I do no think it is a problem of random number. I think it is something of memory (GPU and CPU)  synchronizing.

Comment: With the lack of specific data, you won't get many takers.  Post the values you get internally from both sets of software, especially the places the depend on external initialization.  Also describe in more detail where your partition lies between "Caffe", "Python", and "C++".  Are you working with both Python and C++ implementations of Caffe?